# Insert simple array at specified index inside associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to make array like below :

```
array(

 0 => array (   0 => array (q,a,alt),
                1 => array (q,a,alt),
                2 => array (q,a,alt)
            ),

 1 => array (   0 => array (q,a,alt),
                1 => array (q,a,alt),
                2 => array (q,a,alt)
            ),

 2 => array (   0 => array (q,a,alt),
                1 => array (q,a,alt),
                2 => array (q,a,alt)
            )

  );
```

I have gone through all over I couldn't get solution anywhere. Below is my code :

```
<?php 

$mainArray = array();

$ans = array('q', 'a', 'att');

for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $mainArray[$i] = array();

    for($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
        $mainArray[$i][$j] = array('q','a','att');
    }
}

print_r($mainArray);

?>
```

What I get is something wrong.

Below is my output :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => q [1] => a [2] => att ) [1] => Array ( [0] => q [1] => a [2] => att ) [2] => Array ( [0] => q [1] => a [2] => att ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => q [1] => a [2] => att ) [1] => Array ( [0] => q [1] => a [2] => att ) [2] => Array ( [0] => q [1] => a [2] => att ) ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => q [1] => a [2] => att ) [1] => Array ( [0] => q [1] => a [2] => att ) [2] => Array ( [0] => q [1] => a [2] => att ) ) )
```

Comment: Should `'att'` be `'alt'`?

Comment: As far as I can tell the routine is giving exactly the output you want, just that you have `array (q,a,alt)` which is expanded in the actual output you get (`Array ( [0] => q [1] => a [2] => att )`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually much easier than you think.

PHP has a function called array_fill which will create an array 'from key' to 'number of items' with 'value'.

```
$ans = array('q', 'a', 'att');
$no = 3;

$arr = array_fill(0, $no, $ans);
var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "q"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "att"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "q"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "att"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "q"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "att"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/abRfp

Comment: Thank you for your replay I really appreciated but what is it is not limited to 3 ? I mean make it dynamic.

Comment: No. Not sure what your question is but you can change the $no to be the number of items you want https://3v4l.org/9T0hc

Comment: I want whole new simple array..

0 => array (   0 => array (q,a,alt),
                1 => array (q,a,alt),
                2 => array (q,a,alt)
            ),

Comment: Dynamic in what way? User input dynamic? Weather dynamic? What makes then number of items? Regarding your above comment, yes that is the output.

Comment: Can please tell me where exactly I have to put so that I can get the output.

Comment: The code above gives you the same output as you requested. If you change the $no variable you get a different number of subarrays with $ans items

Comment: Where exactly I need to write inside nested loop ?

Comment: Have you looked at my code? There is no loop. Click on the links and see what the code does.

Comment: Yes I did. At this portion of your output

[0] => Array ( [0] => q [1] => a [2] => att ) [1] => Array ( [0] => q [1] => a [2] => att )

I want something like :

[0] => Array (q, a, att ) [1] => Array ( q, a, att )

Comment: And that is **exactly** what you get. Maybe you need to read up on how arrays work? Go to PHP manual and read the section about arrays